# I need to compare textbox value and table value if already exists then show alert in Asp.net MVC core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to compare user entered value if already exists in database then show an alert using C# only. Presently I am using Javascript to show alert help me any easy way to show that alert.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? Did you consider writing controller action for checking the value in db and calling that controller action via AJAX from javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# is backend language and you can't use it to show alert for user.
You must use JS or other frontend tools to show an alert.